# Unbind shift key with tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

I would like to use tmux+vim. I find very convenient to use the mouse as well to select text. I also use the behave mswin in vim in order to sometime use the to select text.

Unfortunately Tmux already uses the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. Can I bind it to another char or just unbind it?

Comment: Your question, as written, is unclear. When you mention MS Windows behavior, do you mean using shift+arrow keys to select text? And what does tmux use the shift key for? In any event, the shift key isn't something tmux or Vim can handle by itself.